# Anagram solver need sentence to have word limit

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a program that runs over a dictionary which makes anagrams from an inputted string. I found most of the code to this problem here [Algorithm to generate anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210/algorithm-to-generate-anagrams) but i need to have the program only output a line of max amount of words instead of only using words of a set length (MIN_WORD_SIZE).

If the input was: python Anagram.py "Finding Anagrams" 3 dictionary.txt.
The output would be "Gaming fans nadir" because it only uses 3 words at most to create the anagram.
?

Comment: Can you provide more context as well as an example?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean't by word limit?

Comment: Please show your code and specific problem. [ask] [mcve]

Comment: The code i have used is in the link. Its the top answer (42 up votes)

Comment: You said you found "most of the code to this problem."  That still doesn't tell anyone what code you've tried, or what, specifically, the problem is.  Please read the link Julien left to see more on how to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slight work around, however if you only want to *filter* out words that have a length shorter than a specified argument, then you could make a change in your programs main.

Your program currently says:

```
for word in words.anagram(letters):
   print word
```

You could change your program to say:

```
for word in words.anagram(letters):
    if len(word.split()) <= int(argv[2]):
        print word
```

Not the most elegant answer but, I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I don't like to make programs `for` programmers, usually.
To the best of my understanding:

```
import random

word = "scramble"

scramble = list(word)

for i in range(len(scramble)):
    char = scramble.pop(i)
    scramble.insert(random.randint(0,len(word)),char)
print(''.join(scramble))
```

This will scramble the `word` variable.

Hope this helps!

Thanks :)